# JQuery Form Plugin fails with dataType: 'json'

Tags: php, json, jquery-plugins

Having trouble getting a form using PHP, JQuery Form plugin, and JQuery Validate plugin to work as expected. I'm using Validation plugin v 1.8.1, so it is not due to the bug with `dataType: 'json',` being read as `jsonp`. Below is the html:

```
<?php require_once('includes/initialize.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('layouts/header.php'); ?>
<body>
    <div class="container_12">

        <div class="grid_4" id="form">

            <form action="actions/register.php" method="POST" class="cmxform" name="frmPrntRgstr" id="frmPrntRgstr">
        <p>
                <label>Desired Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value="" />
        </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        <p>
                <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="Pwd" id="Pwd" />   
        </p>
            <p>
                <label>Confirm Password:</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirmPwd" id="confirmPwd" />
            </p>
            <div class="clear"></div> 
            <p> 
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="" />
            </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p>
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="" />
            </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p>
                <label>Email Address:</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" />
            </p>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p> 
                <label>Cell Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" id="cellPhone" name="cellPhone" value="" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Home Phone:</label>
                <input type="text" id="homePhone" name="homePhone" value="" />
            </p>
            <input type="hidden" id="role" name="role" value="2" />
            <input type="hidden" id="approved" name="approved" value="0" />
            <input type="hidden" id="school" name="school" value="0" />
            <p>
                 <input class="submit" type="submit" id="regUser" value="Submit" />
            </p>
        </form>
        <p id="frmPrntRgstrRspns" style="display: none;">A Response goes here.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Simplified version of register.php without error checking:

```
<?php require_once('../includes/initialize.php'); ?>
<?php require_once('../layouts/appheader.php'); ?>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST["userName"])) {
    $auser = new User();
    $auser->userName = $_POST['userName'];
    $auser->hshdPwd = sha1($_POST['Pwd']);
    $auser->firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
    $auser->lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    $auser->email = $_POST['email'];
    $auser->cellPhone = $_POST['cellPhone'];
    $auser->homePhone = $_POST['homePhone'];
    if(!is_null($_POST['school'])) {
         $auser->school = $_POST['school'];
    } else {
    $auser->school = "0";   
    }
    $auser->prelim_role = $_POST['role'];
    $auser->approved = $_POST['approved'];
    if($auser->create()) {
    $abc = array('response'=>"Request successfully submitted"); ;
    } else { 
    $abc = array('response'=>"Errors.");
    } 
return ?> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var resp2 = '<?php echo json_encode($abc, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); ?>';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Below is the register.js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$("#frmPrntRgstr").validate({
                    rules: {
                            firstName: "required",
                            lastName: "required",
                            userName: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 6
                            },
                            Pwd: {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 6
                            },
                            confirmPwd: {
                                required: true,
                                minlength: 6,
                                equalTo: '#Pwd'
                            },
                            homePhone: {
                                required: true,
                            },
                            cellPhone: {
                                required: true,
                            },
                            email: {
                                required: true,
                                email: true
                            },
                            },
                            messages: {
                            firstName: "Please enter your firstname",
                            lastName: "Please enter your lastname",
                            userName: {
                                required: "Please enter a username",
                                minlength: "Your username must consist of at least 6 characters"
                            },
                            hshdPwd: {
                                required: "Please provide a password",
                                minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long"
                            },
                            confirmPwd: {
                                required: "Please provide a password",
                                minlength: "Your password must be at least 6 characters long",
                                equalTo: "Please enter the same password as above"
                            },
                            email: "Please enter a valid email address",
                            },
                            submitHandler: function(form) {
                                $("#frmPrntRgstr").ajaxSubmit({
                                                        dataType: 'json',
                                                    success:    processJson,
                                                        })
                            }
});
                function processJson() {
                        var resp3 = $.parseJSON(resp2); 
            $("#frmPrntRgstr").slideUp("normal", function() {
                            $(resp3.response).appendTo("#frmPrntRgstrRspns", function() {
                       $("#frmPrntRgstrRspns").slideDown("normal");
                                 })
            })
                }
});
```

I have tried changing content type to "application/json" in all files. When I remove `dataType: 'json'` and have a success function like `$("#frmPrntRgstr").slideUp("normal", function () { $("#frmPrntRgstrRspns").slideDown("normal") });` everything works fine. When I add `dataType: 'json'`, even when I'm not trying to parse the json server response or use it in the success function, the new user will be inserted into the MySQL database, but the client-side sees no response. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At the risk of more reputation down-voting, problem solved with Dan Grossman's assistance. In case anyone runs into the same issue, register.php (form-processing file) had a `<?php require_once('../layouts/header.php'); ?>` in it. This caused a response that contained that file before the JSONObject. Not sure why that doesn't work, but it doesn't. Now I'm only including the initialize file, and everything works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what your script returns:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var resp2 = '<?php echo json_encode($abc, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); ?>';
</script>
```

This is not JSON, it's a fragment of HTML that contains a script tag with a javascript variable declared inside of it.

A JSON response would look like `<?php echo json_encode($abc); ?>` alone.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. This was my original approach, per a previous answer I've seen you provide to a similar question in the forums. With the above code copied and pasted directly over the script tag currently in the register.php file, I get no client side response. The form submits to the MySQL db, a new record is formed, and the form just sits in its current state.

Comment: Also, how would I call the JSON response to use in the success callback in the register.js file if I've only echoed it in the register.php file?

Comment: First, why is your code "returning" something? What is it returning to? Does what it returns to output the return value? Beyond that, copying and pasting my response atop the existing output just makes it more wrong, not more right. The stuff after the JSON string will continue to be not JSON. Are you sure you get no client side response? Are you looking at network activity in your javascript debugger?

Comment: `success: function(data) { //data is the json object }`

Comment: Firebug is providing no console messages. I plugged in return bc echo hadn't been working. I've edited it to be `if($auser->create()) { $abc = array('response'=>"Request successfully submitted"); echo json_encode($abc);}` and the register.js says `dataType: 'json', success: jsonProcess,` where jsonProcess is `function processJson(data) { 
   $("#frmPrntRgstr").slideUp("normal", function() {
    $("#frmPrntRgstrRspns").append(data.response).slideDown("normal");
   })` I've tried this about a hundred ways with no luck, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Echo the JSON response, and confirm it's in the response body by examining it through Firebug. I don't know the name of the panel, but you're not looking for errors in the console, you want to look at HTTP requests and responses.

Comment: I hadn't used the NET panel before, very new to coding. The Response Headers are `Date Sun, 14 Aug 2011 22:18:02 GMT
Server Apache/2.2.17 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6
X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.6
Content-Length 1219
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
Connection Keep-Alive
Content-Type text/html` I've set the content-type in the register.php form processing file to "application/json" using a meta tag. Is there some other way I should be doing that? The Response panel shows `{"response":"Request successfully submitted"}` which looks like a properly formed JSONObject

Comment: There are no meta tags or other HTML in this response. I think you're thinking about a different page. To set the content-type of the JSON response you write `header("Content-type: application/json");` before you echo the json. Now you need to write the success handler for your AJAX request to do something with that response.